# How Instantiate an Octave Matrix in Shared Memory Allocated With mmap()?

Tags: octave, mmap

How Instantiate an Octave Matrix in Shared Memory Allocated With mmap()?
I tried to use placement but it's not working.

```
void *mem_m = (void *)mmap(NULL, 1000*1000*sizeof(double), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
Matrix *m = new(mem_m) Matrix(1000,1000);
```

I noticed that Octave Matrix allocate dynamically memory for the matrix.

Comment: Sounds like a XY-problem. What is your real problem? And I don't think it's possible to use mmap together with builtin Octave classes.

Comment: But how to share an Octave Matrix with others forked processes?